# Enable faillock on Debian 12

Tags: debian, pam, authentication

Can anyone tell my how to enable faillock on Debian 12?

I had a look to several tutorials but nothing worked for me.

This is what I get after installation - without comments.

**/etc/pam.d/common-account**

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-auth**

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

At least I want logging of failed logins. Further more there should be a lock of users for 3 minutes after 3 failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

this configuration works in debian 12:

```
/etc/pam.d/common-auth

auth    required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=3 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=7200
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=7200
auth    sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=3 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=7200
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so


/etc/pam.d/common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so
account required            pam_faillock.so
```

Regards
Mariano